# How to resolve 'The Azure PowerShell session has not been properly initialized. Please import the module and try again' when loading these modules?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

I working with PowerShell in Azure Functions.

When I try to load AzureRM.ContainerInstance or AzureRM.ContainerRegistry, it seems to succeed, but when I run commands involving those modules, I get this error:

> 2018-03-01T08:50:47  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming
>   service.2018-03-01T08:51:47  No new trace in the past 1
>   min(s).2018-03-01T08:52:47  No new trace in the past 2
>   min(s).2018-03-01T08:53:47  No new trace in the past 3
>   min(s).2018-03-01T08:54:18.995  [Info] Function started
>   (Id=933bbdd1-4e2a-4f71-8481-85e0ca79df12)2018-03-01T08:54:31.075 
>   [Info]
>   Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureContext2018-03-01T08:54:39.320
>   [Error] Get-AzureRmContainerRegistry : The Azure PowerShell session
>   has not been properly initialized.  Please import the module and try
>   again.at run.ps1: line 40+ Get-AzureRmContainerRegistry+
>   ____________________________    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureRmContainerRegistry],
>   InvalidOperationException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ContainerRegistry.GetAzureContainerRegistry2018-03-01T08:54:39.351
>   [Error] Get-AzureRmContainerRegistryCredential : The Azure PowerShell
>   session has not been properly initialized.  Please import the module
>   and try again.at run.ps1: line 41+
>   Get-AzureRmContainerRegistryCredential+
>   ______________________________________    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureRmContainerRegistryCredential],
>   InvalidOperationException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ContainerRegistry.GetAzureContainerRegistryCredential2018-03-01T08:54:39.367
>   [Error] Remove-AzureRmContainerGroup : The Azure PowerShell session
>   has not been properly initialized.  Please import the module and try
>   again.at run.ps1: line 43+ Remove-AzureRmContainerGroup+
>   ____________________________    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-AzureRmContainerGroup],
>   InvalidOperationException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ContainerInstance.RemoveAzureContainerGroupCommand2018-03-01T08:54:39.480
>   [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.CardiViaHttp.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: PowerShell script error.
>   Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions: The Azure
>   PowerShell session has not been properly initialized.  Please import
>   the module and try again.2018-03-01T08:54:39.511 [Error] Function
>   completed (Failure, Id=933bbdd1-4e2a-4f71-8481-85e0ca79df12,
>   Duration=20512ms)

Here's the script I'm building thus far:

```
$TENANTID = "tenant"

$AZUREAPPID ="app1"

$AZURESECRET = "secret"

$SECRETSECURE = $AZURESECRET  | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AZUREAPPID,$SECRETSECURE

Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TENANTID

$RESOURCE_GROUP = "cluster_group";

$CONTAINER_RESOURCE_GROUP = "Containers";

$CLUSTER_NAME = "cluster";

$AKS_NAME = "AKScluster";

$LOGIN_SERVER = "<server>";

$CLUSTER_USER = "<cluster_user>";

$CLUSTER_PASS = "<cluster_pass";

$CONTAINER_NAME = "<container>";

$IMAGE_TAG ="<tag>";

Import-Module "D:\home\site\wwwroot\CardiViaHttp\azuremodules\AzureRM.Profile\4.3.0\AzureRM.Profile.psd1" -Global;

Import-Module "D:\home\site\wwwroot\CardiViaHttp\azuremodules\AzureRM.ContainerInstance\0.2.2\AzureRM.ContainerInstance.psd1" -Global;

Import-Module "D:\home\site\wwwroot\CardiViaHttp\azuremodules\AzureRM.ContainerRegistry\1.0.2\AzureRM.ContainerRegistry.psd1" -Global;

$REGISTRY = Get-AzureRmContainerRegistry -Name $CLUSTER_NAME -ResourceGroupName $RESOURCE_GROUP

$REG_CREDS = Get-AzureRmContainerRegistryCredential  -ResourceGroupName $RESOURCE_GROUP -Name $CLUSTER_NAME 
# $REGISTRY
Remove-AzureRmContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName $RESOURCE_GROUP -Name $CONTAINER_NAME
```

Comment: I got this error several times. What I did was remove all the Azure modules and install again. I don't know if there is any better way but at least re-installation works from my side.

Comment: I'm working in Azure Functions. I don't think re-installation is an option for me.

Comment: Understood. If the main purpose to use PowerShell as a function, I’d highly recommend Azure Automation Runbook which is more compatible with PowerShell